# 403 Forbidden error with Google Calendar

Tags: php, http, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I been trying to access my Google calendar using the calendar api. On my development machine I am able to access the data and display the events on the calendar, but when I push it to the production server I get the following error after giving permission access to the calendar.

Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access /secondavechurch/calendar2.php on
>   this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I made a service account and gave rights to access the calendar to see if it's was the issue, but still get the same error.

Here is my code

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

  $REDIRECT_URI = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/calendar2.php';
  $KEY_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
  $TOKEN_FILE   = "token.txt";

  $SCOPES = array(
      Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY
  );

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Second Ave Church Calendar");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_LOCATION);
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  // Incremental authorization
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

  // Allow access to Google API when the user is not present. 
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");
  $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI);
  $client->setScopes($SCOPES);

  if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) {
      try {
          // Exchange the one-time authorization code for an access token
          $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);

          // Save the access token and refresh token in local filesystem
          file_put_contents($TOKEN_FILE, json_encode($accessToken));

          $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $accessToken;
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($REDIRECT_URI, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
          exit();
      }
      catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e) {
          print_r($e);
      }
  }

  if (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {

      $token = @file_get_contents($TOKEN_FILE);

      if ($token == null) {

          // Generate a URL to request access from Google's OAuth 2.0 server:
          $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

          // Redirect the user to Google's OAuth server
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
          exit();

      } else {

          $_SESSION['accessToken'] = json_decode($token, true);

      }
  }

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

  /* Refresh token when expired */
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

      // the new access token comes with a refresh token as well
      $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
      file_put_contents($TOKEN_FILE, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  $currentEvents = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-1'))) . 'T00:00:00-23:59';
  $currentMonth = date('F');
  $currentYear = date('Y');
  $endDay = get_number_of_days_in_month(date('m'), $currentYear);
  $endOfMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-' . $endDay ))) . 'T00:00:00-23:59';


  $calendarId = 'wayko621@gmail.com';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 100,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
   'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => $currentEvents,
  'timeMax' => $endOfMonth

);
 $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  $Heading =  "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  $Heading =  $currentMonth . " events:\n";

  echo "<div class='calendar'><h2> " . $Heading . "</h2></div>";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    $description = $event->getDescription();
    $formattedDate = date_format(new DateTime($start),"F j, Y - G:i A");
    if (empty($description)){
        $description = "No Description";
    }
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = 'All Day Event';
    }

   echo "<div class='calendar'><h1>" .$event->getSummary() . "</h1>  <h3 class='getdates'>" . $formattedDate . " </h3><br /><span class='description'>" . $description . "</span></div>";
  }
}
 function get_number_of_days_in_month($month, $year) {
    // Using first day of the month, it doesn't really matter
    $date = $year."-".$month."-1";
    return date("t", strtotime($date));
}
```

Thanks for the help with this

Update:
Changed permission to calendar2.php 
Got 500 Internal Server Error

Here is the error log

```
[05-Feb-2018 14:55:51 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in .../secondavechurch/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 78
[05-Feb-2018 14:56:03 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in .../secondavechurch/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 78
[05-Feb-2018 16:20:46 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'file does not exist' in .../secondavechurch/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:839
Stack trace:
#0 .../secondavechurch/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(824): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('CLIENT_SECRET_P...')
#1 .../secondavechurch/oauth2callback.php(13): Google_Client->setAuthConfigFile('CLIENT_SECRET_P...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in .../secondavechurch/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 839
```

Further Update:

This is the error I am getting after configuring error page

```
/secondavechurch/calendar2.php?code=4/aajajkajkdnanfnoaono&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
Error Code: 403
```

Further Update:

Changed code to the following:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=servicea.json');
  $SCOPES = array(
      Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY
  );
  $REDIRECT_URI = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/secondavechurch/calendar3.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");
  $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI);
  $client->setScopes($SCOPES);
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

 $currentEvents = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-1'))) . 'T00:00:00-23:59';
  $currentMonth = date('F');
  $currentYear = date('Y');
  $endDay = get_number_of_days_in_month(date('m'), $currentYear);
  $endOfMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-' . $endDay ))) . 'T00:00:00-23:59';

 $calendarId = 'wayko621@gmail.com';
 $optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 100,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
   'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => $currentEvents,
  'timeMax' => $endOfMonth

);
 $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

 if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  $Heading =  "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  $Heading =  $currentMonth . " events:\n";

  echo "<div class='calendar'><h2> " . $Heading . "</h2></div>";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    $description = $event->getDescription();
    $formattedDate = date_format(new DateTime($start),"F j, Y - G:i A");
    if (empty($description)){
        $description = "No Description";
    }
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = 'All Day Event';
    }

   echo "<div class='calendar'><h1>" .$event->getSummary() . "</h1>  <h3 class='getdates'>" . $formattedDate . " </h3><br /><span class='description'>" . $description . "</span></div>";
  }
}

 function get_number_of_days_in_month($month, $year) {
    // Using first day of the month, it doesn't really matter
    $date = $year."-".$month."-1";
    return date("t", strtotime($date));
}
```

development gets data production doesn't get anything. No error comes up, but when I go to developer tools it shows a 500 error. No error on error log. Maybe I can use try catch in php to see if it does get any error.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with Google calendar.

> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

403 is a web server error.  Its basically a file system error.  The web server doesn't have access to the file.

I am not sure where you are running this but you need to make sure that the web server has access to the file in question.

```
/secondavechurch/calendar2.php
```

Comment: Let me set the permission on the server chmod and see

Comment: changed the permission got new error. 500 internal server error

Comment: seems it doesn't see my file for json auth config but I thought I placed the file on the server. I will verify

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that it was an issue with Composer on the sever side.
curl_reset wasn't working on the on CurlFactory.php.
I commented out the line and it worked.